# What are my remedies if I forgot the password I created during the fundraiser?

Tags: fundraiser, password

I lost the password that I created during the fundraiser.

What are the options I have for recovering it?

Comment: Did you try searching your browser's stored passwords? I just spent a few hours trying to crack the password, then discovered the actual password - complete with a typo that I must have typed twice - in my browser's saved passwords. Phew!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For those that don't have their ICO password it's important to understand that the password you provided was combined with the email you entered into a single passphrase. In order to access your funds you need your Seed words + passphrase (which is email followed by password with no space between).

Before you use a tool to try to brute force the password, first try to verify that you have correctly capitalized the email portion as you try to guess your password.

You can check if you have the correct seedwords, email, and password by using the [official tool](https://tezos.com/pwcheck.html) offline, to be safe.

If that fails you will need to brute force, but there have been many people who thought they had wrong password when in fact something was just incorrectly capitalized.

The Tezos foundation has a new site for those still looking for assistance with password recovery. https://recovery.tezos.com/ Just remember this is crypto and double check all links and use bookmarks to avoid getting phished.

Comment: Official password check tool is just a blank page now?

Comment: (1) Did I understand the above post correctly to say that the password is built from a concatenation of the CAPITALIZED email address and some other (not necessarily capitalized) string?
(2) Were there any other guidelines (constraints) imposed on the password, such as minimum length or "at least one number" or "at least one letter" or "at least one special character" or (important) "only certain special characters"? 

I ask because I am attempting to guess what my password was and none of the passwords I use are working, so maybe they forced me to use something weird.

Comment: No it was not changed. But some people don't realize that they must enter the exact same email as entered originally and that if they change the use of case at all in either the email or the password it will fail. I have edited the answer to add the latest link to the foundation recovery site, but there are also community run groups willing to help. Just be careful when giving anyone private information.

Answer (score 6):

Some other options are brute forcing the password with [this tool](https://github.com/NODESPLIT/tz-brute), built by a community member.

Comment: This tool didn't work for me because there is a missing file: "bitcoin.py". Do you have any idea where I can get the file or do you know of any alternative tool that can help me guess my TEZOS password?