# Forgot password issue

Tags: tezos-base

I'm trying to restore my fund raiser wallet for the first time to access my coins. But I can't seem to remember my password. Is there any option to reset password on the tezbox?

Comment: What do you mean by „reset password on the tezbox“? Did you set Tezbox up with your fundraiser key and protected the wallet with a password, which you now can’t remember? Please be more specific in your question.

Comment: Please add more details, screenshots etc to your question because it is too vague.

Comment: I have closed this question as « unclear what you are asking » until the OP edits his question with more details which will reopen the question.

Answer (score 5):

Hopefully the question can be edited to be clearer, but I do think it is worthwhile to provide an explanation of the different passwords that might be used in accessing the ICO tokens for the first time.

1. **(first password)** To contribute you were asked enter an email and password. These were combined (email+password with no space between) into a case sensitive passphrase that when using the seed words that you were given will allow you to recreate the keys using nearly any wallet software of your choice. This password is not recoverable, you must know it or your only alternative is to brute force. More info here [What are my remedies if I forgot the password I created during the fundraiser?](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/29/what-are-my-remedies-if-i-forgot-the-password-i-created-during-the-fundraiser)
2. **(second password)** In order to activate the account you were required to KYC and in that process you were asked to enter an email and password to create an account to access the KYC portal. These credentials have nothing to do with the first one and as its just a standard web app it has a "recover password" but it wont help you if you lost the first ICO password.
3. **(third password)** This is dependent on the wallet software you choose, but in the case of Tezbox it asked you to create a password to locally encrypt your data. This password is not recoverable because you can always recreate the wallet elsewhere as its only a local password. For example if you lost your computer this local password is now useless, you don't lose your funds you just restore the wallet again and will enter a new local password at that time.